# Finding a related entity which matches one field

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a several (MySQL) tables. The interesting one is the `CampaignRegion` which stores a foreign key to a `Campaign` and one foreign key to either a `City`, `County`, `District`, `State` or `Country`. There is always just one of the location specific foreign keys set, the others are `NULL`.

The `CampaignRegion` table looks like this:

```
mysql> describe CampaignRegion;
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| campaign_id | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| country_id  | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| state_id    | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| district_id | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| county_id   | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| city_id     | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I now need a query to select a `Campaign`. I have a `City` and need to get the `Campaigns` which matches either the `City` itself or the `County` or the `District` or the `State` or the `Country` of the `City`.

This is actually very easy and I came up with something like this:

```
SELECT count(id) as campaign_count, campaign_id
  FROM CampaignRegion
 WHERE (city_id = 32076 OR district_id = 127 OR state_id = 7 OR country_id = 156)
 GROUP BY campaign_id
HAVING campaign_count > 0;
```

However I want to get the result set of `Campaigns` sorted which match the `City` first, then the ones that match the `County`, then the ones that match the `District` and so on (like the order of the `OR` in the query. Is there an easy way of doing this? What would I do to `SELECT` the (first matching) `Campaign` based on this query in a `JOIN` or `SUBSELECT`? What do you think?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT count(id) as campaign_count, campaign_id
FROM CampaignRegion
WHERE (city_id = 32076 OR district_id = 127 OR state_id = 7 OR country_id = 156)
GROUP BY campaign_id
HAVING campaign_count > 0;
ORDER BY (city_id = 32076) DESC, (country_id = 156) DESC, (state_id = 7) DESC, (district_id = 127) DESC;
```